# Acrobat Replace Symbol with Value from Text Field

Tags: javascript, forms, replace, adobe, acrobat

I have a form I am working on in Acrobat DC where I need to be able to type a number into a text field "FieldA" and have it replace a special character @ in a body of text in another text field "FieldB". But only if the number is 1 or greater.

**An example of how I want to use it is:**

**FieldA:** "Fibreboard box x @"

I input 3 into **FieldB**

**FieldA** then because 3 is 1 or greater reads as: "Fibreboard box x 3"

I've been trying to piece this together with the below javascript, this code is applied to "FieldB" under "Properties > Validate > Run custom validation script"

```
if (event.value >= "1")
{
this.getField("FieldA").replace(/\@/g,"event.value");
}
```

You can tell by the javascript that my skills are limited so any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.getField("FieldA").valueAsString.replace(/\@/g, event.value.toString() );
```

At the moment, you replace text in a Field Object, which does, of course, fail. You are interested in the value of the field. And because you are going to use a String Object method on the value, you will better use the `valueAsString` property from Acrobat JavaScript.

You will also want to use `event.value` as replacement, and not the text "event.value". Again, in order to make sure you have a string, force it to a string using the `toString()` method.

Comment: Thank you for helping! I've tried setting that up in my live document but the @ still never gets replaced. I've uploaded the actualy PDF here: [link]https://ufile.io/29220[/link] The field in question is "BOX" which only appears after you select a "kit" from the drop down box. Once a number greater that 0 is entered in "BOX" all of the fields: "2W/C, 6W/C, 12W/C, 18W/C, 6XW, 6XC, DEPRO" should update with the @ in them being replaced by the number.

Comment: Any further help you could provide would be great.